# Prove $T(n)=2F(n+1)-1$ by induction. Please read body for full question.

Tags: algorithms, induction, recursion, fibonacci-numbers, dynamic-programming

Given : $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$ with $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$. $T(n)$ is the total number of calls needed to calculate $F(n)$ using top-down approach.

By writing top-down approach program, I have calculated $T(n)$  i.e., $T(n)=T(n-1)+2$ where $T(0)=T(1)=1$.

I want to prove $T(n)=2F(n+1)-1$ by induction. I'm unable to solve this. Can you please help me out with this proof?

Comment: It's not clear what $T(n)$ is.

Comment: What is top-down approach?

Comment: @K.defaoite $T(n)=T(n−1)+2, T(0)=T(1)=1$.    
$F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2), F(0)=0, F(1)=1$.

Comment: $T(n)$ depends on $T(n-1)$ but the Fibonacci recursion depends on the two previous entries. I don't think they can be the same. Have you actually checked the first few terms of both sequences?

Comment: @EthanBolker I have taken this as a reference to find T(n).https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470716/recurrence-relation-for-tn-of-top-down-approach-solution-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: SUpposed induction step:  $T(n)=2F(n+1)-1$ and so $T(n+1)= T(n)+2 = 2F(n+1)-1+2 = 2F(n+1) + 1\ne 2F(n+2)-1$ in general,  so your conjecture is clearly not true.  Furthermore we can calculate it fails for the first $n$ where $F(n+1) \ne F(n) + 1$.

Comment: Is $T(n)$ is the total number of function calls to evaluate the Fibonacci function $F$? So $T(2)=3$ since $F(2)=F(1)+F(0)$? And $T(3)=5$ since $F(3)=F(2)+F(1)$ and $F(2)=F(1)+F(2)$?

Comment: 1)$ T(4) = 7$ but $2F(5)-1 = 9$ and 2) If $T(n)= T(n-1) +2$ then $T(n)=T(1)+2(n-1)=2n-1=$ then $n$th odd number.

Comment: @fleablood How to find $T(n)$ which is the total number of calls needed to calculate $F(n)$  using top-down approach. I have followed this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74470716/recurrence-relation-for-tn-of-top-down-approach-solution-of-fibonacci-sequence

Comment: The question you link to has an answer: the closed form expression for $T$. The question you ask here is how to prove that the values of $T$ are the Fibonacci numbers. As others have said here, that's just not true.

Comment: "How to find T(n) which is the total number of calls needed to calculate F(n) using top-down approach."  I don't care.....All I am saying is that *if* you calculated $T(n)= T(n-1) + 2$ then it is impossible for $T(n) = 2F(n+1)-1$.  I don't actually *know* if $T(n) = T(n-1) +2$ and I don't care if it is or how you calculated it.  It might very well be true that $T(n)=2F(n+1)-1$, but if it is then $T(n)$ can't be $T(n-1)+2$. (Actually *if* $T(n) = T(n-1)+2$ and $T(1)=1$ then $T(n)=2n-1$ and I very much doubt that is true.)

Comment: The correct recurrence for $T(n)$ is something like $T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1$. $T(n-1)$ and $T(n-2)$ account for the recursive calls, and the $+1$ accounts for the cost of adding them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to prove T(n)=2F(n+1)−1 by induction. I'm unable to solve this.

If you can't solve it by induction that's probably because it isn't true.

We define $T(n) = T(n-1) + 2$ and we are conjecturing that $T(n)=2F(n+1)-1$.

Presumable the first few base cases work.

So we attempt the induction step:

Assume $T(n)=2F(n+1) -1$.  Then $T(n+1) = T(n) +2 = 2F(n+1) -1+2 = 2F(n+1) +1$.

We need to show that this is equal to $2F(n+2)-1$. But $2F(n+2)-1 = 2(F(n+1) +F(n))-1=2F(n+1) + (2F(n) -1)$.

So our induction step will only work if $2F(n) - 1 = 1$.  Not only does our induction step not succeed.  It actively fails.

So our conjecture *can't* be true.

If $T(n) = 2F(n+1) -1$ then $T(n+1) \ne 2F(n+2)-1$ *unless* $F(n) = 1$.  Thus it works for our base cases and it works for $n=3$ (because for $n=2$ we have  $F(2)=1$ so our induction steps works for $n+1=2+1 =3$) but it fails for $n\ge 4$.

Just do it.  $T(0) = T(1)=1; T(2)=1+2 = 3; T(3)=3+2 = 5$; and $T(4)=5+2 =7$.

While $F(0) = 0; F(1)=1; F(2)=1; F(3)=2; F(4)= 3; F(5)=5$

So $2F(0+1)-1=1=T(0); 2F(1+1)-1=1=T(1); 2F(2+1)-1=3=T(2); 2F(3+1)-1=5 =T(3)$ but $2F(4+1)-1=9\ne 7 = T(4)$.